# Contravariance in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, functional-programming

I am new with scala. I am trying to figure out how the whole contravariance relationship works. I understand the concept of covariance and invariant and I also know how I would implement them in practise. 
I also understand the concept of contravariance (the reverse of covariance) and how it is implemented in the Function1 trait in Scala. It gives you an abstraction without redefining Function1 implementations for different classes. But, I still don’t get it completely, strange? Now, I am almost there… how can I solve the following problem with contravariance:

```
class GarbageCan[-A] {

  def doSomething(a: A): Unit ={
    // do something with 'a' of subtype that is not possible with the supertype
  }

}

def setGarbageCanForPlastic(gc: GarbageCan[PlasticItem]): Unit = {

}
```

The above example is extracted from http://blog.kamkor.me/Covariance-And-Contravariance-In-Scala/. A really good explanation concerning this subject. The hierarchy is as follows: Item (base class) -> PlasticItem (subclass) -> PlasticBottle (subclass of subclass)

The setGarbageCanForPlastic function accepts a GarbageCan with the type of PlasticItem. Because the Parameterized type is contravariant, the following statement is completely legal:

```
setGarbageCanForPlastic(new GarbageCan[Item])
```

Now, the doSomething function accepts a Type parameter which is contravariant. How can I work with this type, if I don’t know if the type is a Base class “Item” or subclass “PlasticItem”? I can do something which is permissible within the subclass and not in the base class. If this was an covariant parameter, this would be no problem, a subclass inherits everything from the base class.

I lost it right?... Hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: Why are you only worried about `GarbageCan[Item]`? What is there to prevent someone from creating `GrabageCan[Option[List[Int]]]` for example? Ignore contravariance variance for a moment. Even if it was just `GrabageCan[A]`, how do you imagine your `doSomething` would work?

Comment: Good question... It should only be used as a 'type' within a body?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you mean by "it", and whose "body" you are talking about, so I don't know :) The bottom line is, you _first_ come up with an actual use case, and _then_ see if contravariance/covariance/invariance is appropriate for it, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `doSomething` method actually cannot do anything other than essentially discarding `a` since it does not know what `A` is.  To make it more useful, you would need a bound like `class GarbageCan[-A <: Item]`.

Now, suppose `setGarbageCanForPlastic(gc)` calls `gc.doSomething(new PlasticItem)`.  Since `A` in `GarbageCan[A]` is contravariant, we have `GarbageCan[Item] <: GarbageCan[PlasticItem] <: GarbageCan[PlasticBottle]`.  Indeed, the function call `setGarbageCanForPlastic(new GarbageCan[Item]))` is safe as `GarbageCan[Item]`'s `doSomething` can process any `Item` including a `PlasticItem`, while the call `setGarbageCanForPlastic(new GarbageCan[PlasticBottle]))` is unsafe because `GarbageCan[PlasticBottle]`'s `doSomething` may not be able to take a `PlasticItem` which is not necessarily a `PlasticBottle`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your elaboration.